# opencv image loading using buffer without saving?

Tags: c, opencv, plugins, layer, gimp

plugin for gimp to capture a frame from camera and to load it to gimp workspace.till nw i got the code to capture image and load the image but it is done by saving the captured image but i want to load image without saving the image.

```
#include <libgimp/gimp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <stdio.h>


static void query (void);
static void run   (const gchar      *name,
               gint              nparams,
               const GimpParam  *param,
               gint             *nreturn_vals,
               GimpParam       **return_vals);

GimpPlugInInfo PLUG_IN_INFO =
{
  NULL,
  NULL,
  query,
  run
};

MAIN()

static void
query (void)
{
  static GimpParamDef args[] =
  {
    {
  GIMP_PDB_INT32,
  "run-mode",
  "Run mode"
    },
    {
  GIMP_PDB_IMAGE,
  "image",
  "Input image"
    },
    {
  GIMP_PDB_DRAWABLE,
  "drawable",
  "Input drawable"
    }
  };

  gimp_install_procedure (
    "plug-in-trail",
 "trail, SHOT!",
 "Displays \"trail!\" in a dialog",
 "JOSEPH,ARYA,CHINJU",
 "Copyright To JOSEPH",
 "2013",
 "_trail...",
 "RGB*, GRAY*",
 GIMP_PLUGIN,
 G_N_ELEMENTS (args), 0,
 args, NULL);

gimp_plugin_menu_register ("plug-in-trail",
                         "<Image>/Filters/misc");
}

static void
run (const gchar      *name,
 gint              nparams,
 const GimpParam  *param,
 gint             *nreturn_vals,
 GimpParam       **return_vals)
{
 static GimpParam  values[1];
GimpPDBStatusType status = GIMP_PDB_SUCCESS;
GimpRunMode       run_mode;

*nreturn_vals = 1;
*return_vals  = values;

values[0].type = GIMP_PDB_STATUS;
values[0].data.d_status = status;

 gint32 image_ID;
 gint32 layer_ID;
 run_mode = param[0].data.d_int32;
image_ID = param[1].data.d_image;
CvCapture* camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(0); 

IplImage*     frame = 0;

cvSetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1024) ;
cvSetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,768); 

frame = cvQueryFrame(camera); 

if (frame != NULL) {
printf("Frame extracted from CAM1\n\r");
    cvSaveImage("/bin/test.jpg", frame,0);
} else {
  printf("Null frame 1\n\r");
}
cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
cvReleaseImage(&frame);
layer_ID = gimp_file_load_layer (GIMP_RUN_NONINTERACTIVE,image_ID,"/bin/test.jpg");

gimp_image_add_layer (image_ID,layer_ID,-1);
gimp_displays_flush();
if (run_mode != GIMP_RUN_NONINTERACTIVE)
 g_message("SNAPSHOT TAKEN!!");
}
```

i want to load image without saving the image.how to find layer_id of captured image or i want to know is there any way to load image to gimp without saving captured image?